# Very simple flutter design

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I want to create something in flutter that I don't know the name of. Basically, imagine 3 boxes. The middle one has the text 10, and the right and left have 11 and 9 respectively. The middle box would be bigger than the others, and the left and right slightly smaller but connected. Then, you can swipe and the boxes switch, so the right one becomes the middle, and left one goes away, then a new box appears with the next number in the order. And if you swipe fast, it moves the numbers very fast. Here is an image of the design - Thank you so much!

[image]

Comment: You could use a ListView in a Row Widget. 

Or use this: https://pub.dev/packages/carousel_slider

Comment: @TerrenceSkill how would I use a listview in a row widget? How would I know what container to make bigger than the others? And also would that work with the containers sliding out and in the screen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you are looking for a 3D Carousel/Slider.

https://www.cssscript.com/tag/cover-flow/

I hope that's what you are looking for.

This is specifically for flutter:
https://pub.dev/packages/carousel_slider
More Examples: https://fluttergems.dev/carousel-cover-flow/

Comment: Is this in flutter? I think swiffy slider may be for html and js...

Comment: I updated my answer to include a flutter package, that shoud do what you want (:

Comment: The cssscript.com link is exactly what I want. Is there a way to do that in flutter?

Comment: @CidikoAndorem The closest ones (I could find) to the first one on the sccscript.com link:
https://fluttergems.dev/packages/flutter_carousel_widget/
https://fluttergems.dev/packages/card_swiper/

Comment: Do you know if it would be possible to custom make something like this? None of those work since they all have some default margin, and don't allow custom scaling